# How to include special charactars in regular expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have this regular to convert the post title to a slug , my problem is when I include in my post name a chars like (:,|,?) I got error . and I have no idea of how to make my regular include the special chars ..

Here is my code :

```
public static string MakeUrlFriendly(this string value)
    {
        value = value.ToLowerInvariant();

        value = Regex.Replace(value, @"[^a-z0-9\s-]", "");
        // convert multiple spaces into one space   
        value = Regex.Replace(value, @"\s+", " ").Trim();
        // cut and trim 
        value = value.Substring(0, value.Length <= 70 ? value.Length : 70).Trim();
        value = Regex.Replace(value, @"\s", "-"); // hyphens   


        value = value.ToLowerInvariant().Replace(" ", "-");
        value = Regex.Replace(value, @"[^0-9a-z-]", string.Empty);

        return value;
    }
```

I call it from here :

```
var Myurl = model.Book_name;
            model.UrlSlug = Myurl.MakeUrlFriendly();
```

When I add a post name like : "Functional Anatomy of the Pilates Core: An Illustrated Guide to a Safe"

[image]

I got this error:

[image]

while it should be looks like :functional-anatomy-of-the-pilates-core-an -illustrated-guide-to-a-safe

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but you should be able to just escape the special characters in your regular expression (e.g. \?) Maybe you can post one of the regular expressions that's giving you trouble.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: What's the error? You left it blank.

Comment: The code you've included has nothing to do with your failure case `(:,|,?)`. Please include a code example which directly shows how you're building the regex, your input, your output, and any errors displayed.

Comment: I updated it , sorry for the missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of slowly iterating over and updating your regex to provide a proper file name, why not just remove all invalid characters from the string? We're given the invalid characters, which will work on multiple platforms.

```
var myTitle = "Functional Anatomy of the Pilates Core: An Illustrated Guide to a Safe";
foreach (var invalidChar in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
    myTitle = myTitle.Replace(invalidChar.ToString(),string.Empty);

//Now you can trim spaces, etc
```

Also, when generating a safe URL, you should use the built-in [URL Encode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Actually it's works now , but can you please explain to me more about Url Encode and how to use it ?? or where I should use it

Comment: @FMsw It's used for generating encoded URLs - I'm not sure if you would need it or not - that's up to you, but it's along the same lines as what you're doing, but instead of fixing the file to work on the file system, it fixes it for URLs